# Mobicents DTMF rtp event detection

Tags: sip, mobicents

I found in Mobicents MMS description (http://www.mobicents.org/mms/mms-main.html) i found that it supports DTMF inband and also RFC2833.

In practical tests I found that MS prefer inband DTMF. Is there configuration option to force RFC2833, or is it hardcoded? And if is hardcoded, cound you give me a hint, where should I change it in the code? Example of SDP with codec list looks like:

```
m=audio 11284 RTP/AVP 8 0 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
```